# CLI container not running Hyperledger 1.0 Not able to start (No-TLS) network

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to follow the instructions from the `Hyperledger-fabricdocs Documentation Release master (May 06, 2017)`
When I'm getting to the Start the network (No TLS) section and commenting out the `script.sh` in the CLI container, the following happens

```
$ CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-tls.yaml up -d
Creating network "e2e_default" with the default driver
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating peer0.org1.example.com
Creating peer1.org1.example.com
Creating peer0.org2.example.com
Creating peer1.org2.example.com
Creating cli
$:
```

All containers get created, but immediately after creation the cli container goes down again and I'm back to the `e2e` directory. When running 
`$ docker exec -it cli bash` from the e2e directory obviously I get the error

```
Error response from daemon: Container 41461c41dbecf401eab2b623d5e6930fd37f15979fd15065f87595b29e5d7b47 is not running
```

Has anyone an idea why the cli container stops running while the rest of the containers are still up (status for the cli container shows `Exited 1 minut ago`)? Is this intended and should I move into, for example, the `peer0.org1.example.com` container? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was answered at https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/chaincode-dev by @mastersingh24. The line command: `/bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME};'` should be commented out in the `docker-compose.yaml` file. Also make sure you edited the `docker-compose-template.yaml` file, since the latter overrides the first in the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To simply run every node. just run file ./network_setup.sh up

It will crate genesis blockfile, tx file, crypt-config directory everything. no need to follow manual steps.

after that simply edit file docker-compose-template.yaml. comment link : /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh

run line :
CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-tls.yaml up

Answer (score 0):

@habpygo is correct, it works to comment out that command line in the yaml file, but you can also just set the `$DELAY` and `$TIMEOUT` environment variables (not sure why the tutorial doesn't address that).

Something like this should work:

```
$ export DELAY=1
$ export TIMEOUT=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

After running the below command in the bash for chaincode-docker-devmode:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up
```

In the terminal, you are getting

```
cli exited with code 0
```

firstly, you need to check what are the docker image which is running the system.

you can use the following command,

```
docker ps -a
```

The output will be

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
53a0d41ee0d4        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"           2 minutes ago       Created                                 orderer
```

This is how it will show.

The Second step, 
Remove the docker image by the following command:

```
docker rm 53a0d41ee0d4
```

so this 53a0d41ee0d4 container will be removed.

then again re-rum docker command to check whether any docker image is running or not

```
docker ps
```

The output will be this

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Then run the command mentioned in the

```
README.rst
```

It will work :)